# Cucumber with capybara failed xpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

**Why I'm getting this error ?**

```
undefined method `map' for true:TrueClass
  Did you mean?  tap (NoMethodError)
```

Checking in browser was successful.

**Doing this xpath**:

```
page.find(:xpath, './/td[contains(., "Total Income:")]/following-sibling::td[2]//text()="£ 0.00"')
```

I tried to dissect it,
doing this has no issue: `page.find(:xpath, './/td[contains(., "Total Income:")]')`

Seems error starts after using `following-sibling`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting it because your XPath isn't returning elements, but rather the XPath

```
.//td[contains(., "Total Income:")]/following-sibling::td[2]//text()="£ 0.00"
```

returns a boolean (the result of `text()="£ 0.00"`).  It's not immediately clear exactly which element you're trying to grab - but something along the lines of

```
page.find(:xpath, './/td[contains(., "Total Income:")]/following-sibling::td[2]//*[text()="£ 0.00"'])
```

is probably what you were trying to do.

By the way - what driver are you using with Capybara?

Comment: Thank you so much @Thomas, it works.
I just fixed typo (...//*[text()="£ 0.00"'] => ...//*[text()="£ 0.00"]')